# Help Please: Cant boot Ubuntu after bleachbit froze

Tags: boot, system-installation, 20.04, bleachbit

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.

I was trying to speedup my lapt so i used bleachbit with the Free Disk Space option enabled, then Gnome locked. And i let it keep working... After 20 min the sytstem was unresponsive, so i decided to shut down the laptop, then i tried to restart, after logging in with my password because my disk is encrypted, Ubuntu just doesnt finish booting, i cant get to the Gnome login screen. I already tried recovering my Installation with a live USB but i only have the option of erasing the whole disk and make a new Installation...While using the live USB im able to mount my encrypted disk, and using the Disks application now it says that its full, and it only has 44MB of free space... I tried already many things written in blogs and also from the bleachbit forum, but nothing works.... Any help is deeply appreciated...
Can anybody help me? I am clueless in how to save my installation without reinstalling Ubuntu...

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the Live USB to mount the encrypted disk (like you wrote you did).
2. Delete the folder `~/.cache`, which is where BleachBit writes a large file during the ["wipe free disk space" process](https://docs.bleachbit.org/doc/frequently-asked-questions.html). Also, other programs sometimes write lots of junk here.